# Drag and Drop with NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsstatusitem

I'm trying to write an application that allows the user to drag files from the Finder and drop them onto an `NSStatusItem`.  So far, I've created a custom view that implements the drag and drop interface.  When I add this view as a subview of an `NSWindow` it all works correctly -- the mouse cursor gives appropriate feedback, and when dropped my code gets executed.

However, when I use the same view as an `NSStatusItem's` view it doesn't behave correctly.  The mouse cursor gives appropriate feedback indicating that the file can be dropped, but when I drop the file my drop code never gets executed.

Is there something special I need to do to enable drag and drop with an `NSStatusItem`?

Answer (score 30):

I finally got around to testing this and it works perfectly, so there's definitely something wrong with your code.

Here's a custom view that allows dragging:

```
@implementation DragStatusView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //register for drags
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    //the status item will just be a yellow rectangle
    [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}

//we want to copy the files
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

//perform the drag and log the files that are dropped
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender 
{
    NSPasteboard *pboard;
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask;

    sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] ) {
        NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

        NSLog(@"Files: %@",files);
    }
    return YES;
}


@end
```

Here's how you'd create the status item:

```
NSStatusItem* item = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];

DragStatusView* dragView = [[DragStatusView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 24, 24)];
[item setView:dragView];
[dragView release];
```

Comment: Awesome! But how I can handle click on this view and show menu?

Comment: @Oleg were you able to implement click handling and displaying a menu on this view?

Comment: I add button. And then add DragStatusView as subview.

 `_titleButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, -2, 26, 24)];
 [_titleButton setBordered:NO];
 [_titleButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
 [_titleButton setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
 [_titleButton setBezelStyle:NSThickerSquareBezelStyle];
 [_titleButton setTarget:self];   
 [_titleButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"IconDefault.png"]];
 
 [_titleButton setAction:@selector(showMenu:)];
  
 self.view = [[ILDragStatusView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 1, 26, 24)];
 [self.view addSubview:_titleButton];`

Answer (score 14):

Since Yosemite, the method for setting a view on `NSStatusItem` is deprecated but fortunately there is a much nicer way using the new `NSStatusItemButton` property on `NSStatusItem`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
    NSImage *icon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"iconName"];
    //This is the only way to be compatible to all ~30 menu styles (e.g. dark mode) available in Yosemite
    [normalImage setTemplate:YES];
    statusItem.button.image = normalImage;

    // register with an array of types you'd like to accept
    [statusItem.button.window registerForDraggedTypes:@[NSFilenamesPboardType]];
    statusItem.button.window.delegate = self;
```

}

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
  //drag handling logic
}
```

Please be aware that the `button` property is only available starting in 10.10 and you might have to keep your old solution if you support 10.9 Mavericks or below.

Comment: Thanks very much. For some reason, this doesn't work when I drag the file from the dock's "Downloads" stack (works fine from Finder). Any idea why that may be happening?

Comment: @CoffeeBite I'm running into the same issue, as reported in this radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1745403. Have you eventually found a way to solve this?

Comment: @Pim Yes. The `performDragOperation` isn't called, but `draggingEnded` is. So I check if the dragging ended within the frame of the status menu item. 

```
func draggingEnded(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        if sender != nil {
            if NSPointInRect(sender!.draggingLocation(), statusItem.button.frame) {
                if let pasteboard: NSPasteboard = sender!.draggingPasteboard() {
                    //get file from clipboard data and do stuff.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```