# [Mac]How to reproduce drag and drop from cloudapp in the system bar menu?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, menubar

I'm trying to reproduce the drag and drop into the system bar menu of cloudapp for mac.
I've done some search but doesn't find anything that could help me.
To create the menu I followed this tutorial http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/creating-a-status-bar-application/ but now I'm stuck on the drag and drop.

Does anyone now how to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop with NSStatusItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663887/drag-and-drop-with-nsstatusitem)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a custom view in your `NSStatusItem` and implement drag and drop in that view.

I posted example code in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493240/50122).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just not found it.