# Menu closes during Drag and Drop with NSStatusItem

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6, nsstatusitem

This question is in response to [Drag and Drop with NSStatusItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663887/drag-and-drop-with-nsstatusitem/18603973#18603973)

The code from @rob Keniger works for me. Following these exact steps, When I run the app, click the menu bar icon, I can drag things to my drag area and everything works. My problem is if I run the app, (then instead of clicking the menu icon first) click Finder, then click the menu bar icon, when I try to drag, the menu closes as I'm dragging.

How do I make the menu view stay open every time the user has the menu open and is dragging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to do this:

[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];