# registerForDraggedTypes with NSStatusBarButton?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, osx-yosemite, nsstatusbar

I'm trying to implement file drag and drop with an NSStatusBarItem.

All I really have is `statusBarItem.button!.window?.registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType])`, but I don't know how or where to actually override methods like `draggingEntered` and `performDragOperation`.

I know it can be done with a custom view, but I'd like to stay away from deprecated methods if possible.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663887/drag-and-drop-with-nsstatusitem

Comment: I've tried that method, but the dragging methods aren't actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

NSButton inherits from NSView. Therefore you can overlay a custom view which implements drag and drop functionality and add it as a subview to the NSButton. This approach avoids deprecated methods.